# Passing structure into ISR

Tags: c, pic, microchip, isr

I am programming in C using Hi-Tech-PICC v9.65PL1 to program a PIC16F876.

For interrupts I am using the structure:

```
void interrupt isr() {
    if (T0IF) {
               //Do STUFF
     T0IF = 0;
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to pass an object into the ISR. I know I could simple make the object a global variable, but that is not the point. I have seen it done in C with another architecture. Since I am using C, when I say an object, I am referring to a typedef struct, such as:

```
typedef struct {
    volatile char state;
    rtc_t rtc;
    shiftReg_t shiftReg;
} clock_t;
```

My goal is to have the ISR change the "state" within the clock_t structure.

Can some please explain what is involved with doing this?

Comment: How was that done on that different architecture you're referring to?

Comment: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/prog/inthandler.html, under the heading "Updating common data structures", about halfway down the page.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, given that the architecture is not that different, you would need to perform an atomic operation for changing the state in the clock_t structure.

That said, can `void interrupt isr()` take a parameter? If yes, then you *can* use a local clock_t structure, else the best bet would be to go with a global variable.

If the isr does accept the parameter, you could go as:

```
int main()
{
    clock_t noteState;
    ....
    isr(&noteState);
    ....
}
```

and the isr definition as::

```
void interrupt isr(clock_t *tmp)
{
    interruptDisable(); // I am guessing that T0IF is a global value, yes?
    /* Perform operation */
    tmp->state = newState /*(whatever you choose to set)*/
    interruptEnable();
}
```

You can then reuse noteState in future :)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the variable update in IRQ is "atomic", if the variable can be updated in one instruction like increment, decrement, only read, only write. So you don't need disable and enable interrupt for bare-c code on IRQ Handler.Some OS coders provides you functions for those situations, to be sure that the variable is updated with single instruction. Example OS function: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/a/atomic_add.html

For some other cases, read/modify/write operations are not atomic on most cpus (though they /are/ atomic on some CISC cpus), and there is no guarantee of atomicity when accessing multiple variables. For those cases, before variable updates enter_critical_section() and after variable updates exit_critical_section() functions are used. For bare-c (non-OS) cases these functions reduced  to interruptEnable() and interruptDisable() functions.